# list.index ValueError occuring even though the value is present in python

Tags: python, indexing, max

I'm trying to get the index at which there is the highest number of a list but after a bit it stops working even though the value to search is present in the list.

```
closest_vertex = vertex[:][2].index(max([vertex[i][2]] for i, _ in enumerate(vertex))[0])
```

I want it to seatch between the third values of the lists in vertex and it works initially.

Comment: Is that `numpy`? Can't you use something like [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax) instead of using `max` on enumerate, then `index`? Can you show a small (!) example for `vertex` and expected output?

Comment: It's not numpy, it's the python built-in list type.
Vertex is initially defined as:
`vertex = [[100, 100, 100], [100, -100, 100], [-100, -100, 100], [-100, 100, 100], [100, 100, -100], [100, -100, -100], [-100, -100, -100], [-100, 100, -100]]`

Comment: There are a lot of weird things going on in your code, and your example does not really help in figuring out what it should do. Do you want the row and/or column of the max element? Or (as you do now) the index of the max element in just the 3rd (index 2) sub-list in the list-of-lists?

Comment: The index of the max element in just the 3rd (index 2) sub-list in the list-of-lists.

Comment: It might be an idea to show some sample data for *vertex* and what you're trying to get out of it. Why you're making a copy of *vertex* is very mysterious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is (most likely) not doing what you expect it to do. Let's unpack that line:

1. `max([vertex[i][2]] for i, _ in enumerate(vertex))[0]` you get the `max` element of all the elements at index 2 of all the sub-lists. A more concise way for this would be `max(x[2] for x in vertex)`
2. `vertex[:][2].index(...)` first, `[:]` just creates a copy of the list, then you get the sub-list at index 2, then you try to find the index of the element from (1)

So the problem is that (1) gets the max element in *column* 2, but then you try to find that element's position in *row* 2. In your minimal example, this coincidentally works, but not always.

---

> vertex is a list of 3d points which are lists of 3 numbers storing x y z axis coordinate, I want to know which point has the highest z value.

In this case, you should just use `max` with a `key` function to get the point with max z directly

```
>>> max_z_point = max(vertex, key=lambda p: p[2])
>>> max_z_point
[100, 100, 100]
```

If you really need the index, you can then get that, too, of course:

```
>>> vertex.index(max_z_point)
0
```

If you want the indices of all points with maximal z value (there can be more), try this:

```
>>> max_z = max(x[2] for x in vertex)
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(vertex) if x[2] == max_z]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I agree on 1, I didn't think of it. As of 2 I put [:] because I had to specify [2] after it and didn't know what to put in the first [] so I put : thinking it would take the whole list.

Comment: @MattiaDemontis You probably though of `numpy`'s `vertex[:,2]`...

Comment: I suppose? I never used numpy

Comment: @MattiaDemontis So what exactly do you want? The index of the sub-list in `vertex` where the 3rd element is maximal? Or just the index of the maximal element in the 3rd sub-list?

Comment: I'll try explaining what vertex is so it might be more clear: vertex is a list of 3d points which are lists of 3 numbers storing x y z axis coordinate, I want to know which point has the highest z value.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, I guess vertex[:][2].index was what was messing the code before. Now it seems to work fine.